Should there be an enchaînement between "plus" and "indéniable" in this sentence?

Cette coiffure te donne un plus indéniable.

I've learned that there should not be an enchaînement between "un plus" and "indéniable" somewhere, which means it shouldn't be pronunced as [œ̃-ply-sɛ̃-de-njabl], but I don't know why. I mean here "plus" is a noun prounced as [plys] and "un plus indéniable" is a groupe rythmique, why shouldn't I connect the [s] in [plys] and [ɛ̃] in [ɛ̃denjabl]?
You can see the related question on HiNative here: question about enchaînement. Merci beaucoup!

Comments have been moved to chat.

This question is similar to: When does one pronounce the 's' in plus?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

When you split the phrase un plus indéniable in syllables, the S of plus belongs to the syllable of that word so that gives the five syllables /œ̃.plys.ɛ̃.de.njabl/. Because the substantive plus is used and not the adverb plus, we generally chose to end the groupe rythmique so the enchaînement is not realized.
Here are three examples of native French pronunciation of un plus indéniable that can be found in YouTube. None of them exhibits an enchaînement while the pause between between plus and indéniable vary:

YouTube 3'33"

YouTube 2'17"

YouTube 3'57"


The faster you pronounce it, the shorter the inter-syllables pauses will be so that will give the impression that there is no pause between the syllables but I guess audio analysis will still show that the /y/ and the /s/ are closely linked. On the opposite, if you strongly mark the pauses between syllables, pronouncing /œ̃...ply...sɛ̃...de...njabl/ would sound unnatural.
You might compare it with the sentence C'est plus sain where the S of plus is almost always dropped. The sentence is typically pronounced /sɛ.ply.sɛ̃/ because there is a single groupe rythmique. Saying /sɛ.plys.ɛ̃/ would risk to be misunderstood as C plus un, at least in Northern France.

Thanks for the answer! So it's about the essence of enchaînement? I mean, in a phrase like "une amie", the syllables are /yn.a.mi/ but not /y.na.mi/, and if I prounce it as /y...na...mi/, it will also sound unnatural?

Good follow up question. It's a case where the word boundary is less marked so both variants would sound natural. There is no ambiguity between /y/ and /yn/. The masculine un ami is syllabified to /œ̃.na.mi/ so the feminine tends to follow. It's like if the noun was nami(e) (or zami(e) in plural. )

@jiliagre Some sources would have it as /œ̃.ply.sɛ̃.de.njabl/ instead ("s" not part of "plu" syllable. I guess we need to distinguish enchaînement in the field of phonetics from the way we think we chain words in everyday speech.

@guillaume31 Unless I'm mistaken, the source you linked doesn't include un plus indéniable or un plus (subtantive) followed by a vowel. Answer updated with real life pronunciations.

@jiliagre It's a general rule (Si le premier mot finit par une consonne prononcée et que le mot suivant [...]) I don't see why "plus" would be an exception.

@guillaume31 Either you are deaf or don't want to acknowledge the obvious. In either case I can't help more. Better for us to stop here.

Really thank you for the answer. I recognised it indeed is because “un plus indéniable” is not a single groupe rythmique as I thought before. And so sorry for the unnecessary trouble I caused.

@guillaume31 The statement that there should not be an enchaînement in the question is from a website not in English nor in French, so I did not write it down at first. But if you don’t mind, I will show it. So sorry for the misunderstanding!

@jiliagre I added my own answer. Maybe you will understand what I mean.

@guillaume31 When usage doesn't follow the rules, I believe the rules or better, their interpretation, should be questioned, not the usage.

@jiliagre My point exactly when I wrote "we need to distinguish enchaînement in the field of phonetics from the way we think we chain words in everyday speech". There is a degree of sophistication at which these rules become useless, or worse, counterproductive, for foreign learners.

@guillaume31 I'm not basing my reply on "the way we think we chain words when we speak" but  on "the way actual people do pronounce this expression" and I provide three examples to support it. The OP asked about real life pronunciation, not statements based on rules. If you hear these YouTube examples, there is clearly a stress on plus in all of them so plus and indéniable do not belong to the same groupe rythmique for these native speakers. PS: You mistype my username.

@jlliagre I don't know what to say except that it proves my point that very specialized theory and practice are not always aligned, hence the need for posters to specify what they want. I could also provide dozens of examples where the expression is chained, I'll come up with some links when I have the time.

@guillaume31 Feel free to do it if you can. Your comment seems to imply I cherry picked my examples. This is incorrect. These three videos are the only ones found by a YouTube specialized search engine (YouGlish).

It is not obvious from your question if you come from an academics perspective or a foreign language learner perspective.
If you just want to know how the sentence is pronounced, the answer proposed as duplicate by several commenters has ample enough information.
From a phonetic point of view, here's what I found: there is always an enchaînement, in the linguistics sense, when a word ends with a consonant and the next begins with a vowel sound. See explanations here, there.

Si le premier mot finit par une consonne prononcée et que le mot suivant commence par une
voyelle, la consonne finale s’enchaîne au mot suivant comme une attaque.

In your example, as "plus" is a noun (last bullet point of case 2 in the duplicate answer) so the final consonant "s" is always pronounced, and as the next word begins with a vowel, there must also be an enchaînement.
The end consonant is recombined into the syllable of the next word, which makes it [ply.sɛ̃.de.njabl].
It is similar to:
Un abribus aérien

Un prospectus emballé

etc.


I've learned that there should not be an enchaînement

I'm not sure why, from a linguistics point of view it seems to be a misunderstanding.

I think there are indeed many people who would avoid the enchaînement

I'm not sure about "many" people, but maybe some do it because they want to emphasize "indéniable" and they pause slightly between the words. It is definitely not a rule (or an identified exception to the rule) - actually you'll hear a thousand shades of pauses or emphasis in the wild... it's the difference between theory and practice.
